# Display a.json table in an html page

Tags: javascript

I would like to display a table in an html page.
Currently, here is what emerges:

> undefined

- Create a paragraph that will host the table
- Read the table and store it in a variable
- Display the table as a console
- InnerHTML of the table in the paragraph that should contain it.

```js
var testJson = $.getJSON("..\\..\\jsconfig.json").responseText;
console.log(testJson);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testJson;

// Tableau .json

var Tableau = {
  "GROUPES": [{
      "PROJECT": "google",
      "SITES": [{
          "NAME": "google"
        },
        {
          "NAME": "youtube"
        }
      ],
      "URL": [{
          "TEST": "https://www.google.fr/"
        },
        {
          "TEST": "https://www.youtube.com/"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "PROJECT": "facebook",
      "SITES": [{
          "NAME": "facebook"
        },
        {
          "NAME": "instagram"
        }
      ],
      "URL": [{
          "TEST": "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=fr"
        },
        {
          "TEST": "https://fr-fr.facebook.com/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Hi Alexandre, welcome! What have you tried yourself to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure this path is valid ? "..\\..\\jsconfig.json"

Comment: u have any error in network?

Comment: `console.log(__dirname);` and double check your JSON file path

Comment: Hi everybody, thanks for your answer ! The path looks good so I don't know where can be the error

Comment: In the line : var testJson = $.getJSON("..\\..\\jsconfig.json").responseText;                         I removed the .responseText and now I can see : {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,....} when I press F12 and go in the console where it had written : undefined                                                                                                          I can see my table in the line named : responseJSON                                                           How can I get only this line and return her in console.log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs at: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

getJSON takes a callback instead of responseText.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("/path/to/data.json", function (data) {
    $('#demo').html(JSON.stringify(data))
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! It work ! I'm gonna add some CSS and I think it gonna be perfect